# React build failing in Azure Devops even after setting NODE_OPTIONS= --openssl-legacy-provider for Node v18.14.2

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, azure-devops, openssl

My react build works locally for Node v18.14.2 and by setting NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider.
But, the same command didn't work in Azure DevOps. Did anyone face the same issue?

My build prod command from package.json
    `"build:prod": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && lingui add-locale en && lingui extract --clean && lingui compile && webpack --mode production",` This does work fine.

Here's the log from Azure DevOps job,

```
2023-03-10T21:33:16.0918322Z ##[section]Starting: Build React
2023-03-10T21:33:16.0924616Z ==============================================================================
2023-03-10T21:33:16.0925038Z Task         : npm
2023-03-10T21:33:16.0925215Z Description  : Install and publish npm packages, or run an npm command. Supports npmjs.com and authenticated registries like Azure Artifacts.
2023-03-10T21:33:16.0925503Z Version      : 1.215.1
2023-03-10T21:33:16.0925657Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2023-03-10T21:33:16.0925794Z Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/npm
2023-03-10T21:33:16.0925989Z ==============================================================================
2023-03-10T21:33:16.8173269Z [command]/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/18.14.2/x64/bin/npm --version
2023-03-10T21:33:17.8478290Z 9.5.0
2023-03-10T21:33:18.9258509Z [command]/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/18.14.2/x64/bin/npm config list
2023-03-10T21:33:19.4446323Z ; "env" config from environment
2023-03-10T21:33:19.4447207Z 
2023-03-10T21:33:19.4449231Z userconfig = "/home/vsts/work/1/npm/38131.npmrc" 
2023-03-10T21:33:19.4449670Z 
2023-03-10T21:33:19.4450475Z ; node bin location = /opt/hostedtoolcache/node/18.14.2/x64/bin/node
2023-03-10T21:33:19.4450948Z ; node version = v18.14.2
2023-03-10T21:33:19.4451544Z ; npm local prefix = /home/vsts/work/1/s/
2023-03-10T21:33:19.4452121Z ; npm version = 9.5.0
2023-03-10T21:33:19.4452923Z ; cwd = /home/vsts/work/1/s/
2023-03-10T21:33:19.4453584Z ; HOME = /home/vsts
2023-03-10T21:33:19.4454339Z ; Run `npm config ls -l` to show all defaults.
2023-03-10T21:33:19.4457332Z [command]/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/18.14.2/x64/bin/npm run build:prod
2023-03-10T21:34:04.0658164Z Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
2023-03-10T21:34:04.0658830Z 
2023-03-10T21:34:05.0680734Z npx browserslist@latest --update-db
2023-03-10T21:34:05.0682791Z > react2@1.0.0 build:prod
2023-03-10T21:34:05.0683433Z 
2023-03-10T21:34:05.0684081Z > set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && lingui add-locale en && lingui extract --clean && lingui compile && webpack --mode production
2023-03-10T21:34:05.0684715Z Why you should do it regularly:
2023-03-10T21:34:05.0685266Z 
2023-03-10T21:34:05.0685909Z https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browsers-data-updating
2023-03-10T21:34:05.0686247Z Added locale en.
2023-03-10T21:34:05.0686976Z Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
2023-03-10T21:34:05.0687202Z 
2023-03-10T21:34:05.0687577Z npx browserslist@latest --update-db
2023-03-10T21:34:05.0687905Z (use "npm run extract" to extract messages)
2023-03-10T21:34:05.0688244Z 
2023-03-10T21:34:05.0688537Z Catalog statistics:
2023-03-10T21:34:05.0689026Z Why you should do it regularly:
2023-03-10T21:34:05.0689568Z ┌─────────────┬─────────────┬─────────┐
2023-03-10T21:34:05.0690236Z https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browsers-data-updating
2023-03-10T21:34:05.0690816Z │ Language    │ Total count │ Missing │
2023-03-10T21:34:05.0691282Z node:internal/crypto/hash:71
2023-03-10T21:34:05.0691987Z ├─────────────┼─────────────┼─────────┤
2023-03-10T21:34:05.0692511Z   this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
2023-03-10T21:34:05.0693042Z │ en (source) │     588     │    -    │
2023-03-10T21:34:05.0693540Z                   ^
2023-03-10T21:34:05.0694049Z └─────────────┴─────────────┴─────────┘
2023-03-10T21:34:05.0694404Z 
2023-03-10T21:34:05.0694683Z 
2023-03-10T21:34:05.0695114Z Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
2023-03-10T21:34:05.0695974Z (use "npm run add-locale <locale>" to add more locales)
2023-03-10T21:34:05.0697592Z     at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
2023-03-10T21:34:05.0699716Z (use "npm run extract" to update catalogs with new messages)
2023-03-10T21:34:05.0721007Z     at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
2023-03-10T21:34:05.0721681Z (use "npm run compile" to compile catalogs for production)
2023-03-10T21:34:05.0722411Z     at module.exports /home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:59:71
2023-03-10T21:34:05.0738711Z     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
2023-03-10T21:34:05.0941251Z   opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
2023-03-10T21:34:06.0666100Z   library: 'digital envelope routines',
2023-03-10T21:34:06.0667859Z   reason: 'unsupported',
2023-03-10T21:34:06.0668794Z   code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
2023-03-10T21:34:06.0669561Z }
2023-03-10T21:34:06.0670138Z 
2023-03-10T21:34:06.0931378Z Node.js v18.14.2
2023-03-10T21:34:06.0975355Z ##[warning]Couldn't find a debug log in the cache or working directory
2023-03-10T21:34:06.0988508Z ##[error]Error: Npm failed with return code: 1
2023-03-10T21:34:06.1002980Z ##[section]Finishing: Build React
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by this way:

Updated my package.json like this:

```
"scripts": {     
    "dev": "cross-env ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development NODE_ENV=development dotnet run",
 
    "build": "**set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider &&** npm run build-vendor:prod && npm run build:prod", 

    "build:prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules",
 
    "build-vendor:prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js --progress",
}
```